# Does map(None, some_list) do anything useful with one list in Python 2.7?

Tags: python-2.7, list, dictionary

I found this in some legacy code.

```
list_2 = []
for x in map(None, list_1):
    list_2.append(x)
```

As far as I can tell this code is pointless and produces the same result as

```
list_2 = list_1
```

Am I missing something?

I googled it for hours, looked into python docs but could not find an answer to this specific case.
P.S. We are converting code from Python 2 to 3.

edit: Values in the list are strings  e.g. ['21', '13C', 'A:32A', ''] (some may be empty strings).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best reference I can find is [here](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/functions/map.html):

> If function is None, the identity function is assumed;

Which means `map(None, xs)` essentially makes a lazy, shallow copy of `xs`. The confusing thing though is that the shallow copy is immediately iterated in a `for`, so it's unnecessary.

My guess: originally, `None` was an actual transforming function. They decided they didn't need that transformation any more though (or moved it somewhere else), but left the "skeleton" in place in case they needed to easily reverse the change in the  future (although that appears to never have happened). Even that doesn't make perfect sense though, as the whole for loop could have been replaced with a call to `list` to force the `map`, but hey, people write weird stuff sometimes.

It is *not* equivalent to `list_2 = list_1` though, since that makes the two references point to the same list. It does however seem to be equivalent to either of

```
list_2 = list(list_1)
list_2 = list_1[:]
```

Which make shallow copies of `list_1`, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list).

Answer (score 2):

This code makes a deep copy of the list instead of copying the pointer to the list.
So alterations to `list_1` later won't have an effect on `list_2`.

```
>>> list_1 = [1,2,3,4] 
>>> list_2 = [] 
>>> for x in map(None, list_1):
...     list_2.append(x)
...  
>>> list_2       
[1, 2, 3, 4] 
>>> list_3 = list_1 
>>> list_1[0] = 9 
>>> list_1 
[9, 2, 3, 4] 
>>> list_2 
[1, 2, 3, 4] 
>>> list_3 
[9, 2, 3, 4] 
>>>
```